# Java Декстоп. Иконка файла

Tags: java, jar

Салам всем. Вот только начал изучать Java и хотел бы написать программу на декстоп. Но вот не нашел нигде как поменять у самого .jar файла иконку с крушкой на нужную иконку. Найденные примеры все меняют иконку JFrame наверху а мне нужно на сам файл. Как это нужно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что ОС видят jar как архив, а не как executable. Поэтому операционная система назначает всем jar такую иконку. Вы можете создать Launcher для своей программы, а Launcher в свою очередь  будет поставлять иконку и запускать jar. Есть много готовых решений этой проблемы, например [самое популярное кроссплатформенное решение.](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Comment: это получается .exe которое включает .jar?

Comment: @user8978194 да, там есть много опций, которые настраиваются в config.xml, там всё есть в документации, можно вообще получить один .exe, а не указывать путь к вашему jar, чтобы никто его даже не видел.